# Add canvas between line in itext 7 Without Overlapping Page

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

Is it possible to add canvas along with the addParagraph to the document? i have long text(1000 page).

I need to add canvas between text in certain places(graphics, shapes, etc.).

For example, if there is a word "graph_add" in the text

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
PageSize ps = PageSize.A4;;
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, ps);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bigfileWithText.txt"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
if("graph_add".equals(line))
//Add canvas in document in this place!!doc.add(Canvas)
doc.add(new Paragraph(line)
}
doc.close();
```

this is example file:
[image: bigfileWithText.txt]

this article 
https://itextpdf.com/ru/resources/books/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-adding-content-canvas-or-document does not fit, here i need to create on a separate page. I  in a certain moment after the text add a figure(Canvas) and then add again a text.
Something like this: [image: example image]

Comment: maybe you could add a [Div](https://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Div.html) element of the desired [height](https://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/element/BlockElement.html#setHeight-float-)

Comment: @Stef ,I cannot add canvas in div element(

Comment: You are aware that the test `line =="graph_add"` in Java most likely does not do what you want? It does not check whether `line` is a string with the same characters as `"graph_add"`, instead it checks whether `line` is the identical string instance as that `"graph_add"` string. Most likely you want to use `"graph_add".equals(line)` instead.

Comment: @ mkl yes, i know

Comment: Ah, ok, you corrected your code. So what exactly happens if you try to add a `Canvas` to your document? And how exactly do you try?

Comment: i need to add canvas between text when i'm reading txt file. i can't do it  without Overlapping Page.that is, I need to  add text (from file) , then to add canvas(example shape(sent by user)) , then again to add text(from the same file).

Comment: @mkl, User send  text and canvas in textarea or file. Just whites text and chooses the shape in table and then  shapes name inserted into the text(graph_add).Then shapes name draw and after add in the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What to Add

First of all, you cannot simply add a `Canvas` to something because a `Canvas` merely is a helper for adding content directly onto a specified `PdfCanvas`, a bridge between different API levels, cf. its JavaDoc:

```java
/**
 * This class is used for adding content directly onto a specified {@link PdfCanvas}.
 * {@link Canvas} does not know the concept of a page, so it can't reflow to a 'next' {@link Canvas}.
 *
 * This class effectively acts as a bridge between the high-level <em>layout</em>
 * API and the low-level <em>kernel</em> API.
 */
public class Canvas extends RootElement<Canvas>
```

For a similar reason you cannot add a `PdfCanvas` because it also merely is a helper for adding content directly into a content stream of a page or form XObject:

```java
/**
 * PdfCanvas class represents an algorithm for writing data into content stream.
 * To write into page content, create PdfCanvas from a page instance.
 * To write into form XObject, create PdfCanvas from a form XObject instance.
 * Make sure to call PdfCanvas.release() after you finished writing to the canvas.
 * It will save some memory.
 */
public class PdfCanvas implements Serializable
```

What you can add to something, though, is a form XObject after wrapping it into an `Image`.

Thus, you should first create a form XObject, then a `PdfCanvas`, then a `Canvas`, and fill the `Canvas` with your content:

```java
PdfFormXObject pdfFormXObject = new PdfFormXObject(XOBJECT_SIZE);
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfFormXObject, pdfDoc);
try (Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, pdfFormXObject.getBBox().toRectangle())) {
    ADD CONTENT TO canvas AS REQUIRED FOR THE USE CASE IN QUESTION
}
```

Then you can wrap the form XObject in an `Image` and add it to the document:

```java
doc.add(new Image(pdfFormXObject));
```

#### An Example

I used your example text and graph image (stored as "Graph.png"):

```java
String text = "Until recently, increasing dividend yields grabbed the headlines. However, increasing\n" + 
        "yields were actually more a reflection of the market capitalisation challenge than of the\n" + 
        "fortunes of mining shareholders. The yields mask a complete u-turn from boom-time\n" + 
        "dividend policies. More companies have now announced clear percentages of profit\n" + 
        "distribution policies. The big story today is the abandonment of progressive dividends\n" + 
        "by the majors, confirming that no miner was immune from a sustained commodity\n" + 
        "cycle downturn, however diversified their portfolio. \n" +
        "\ngraph_add\n\n" +
        "Shareholders were not fully rewarded for the high commodity prices and huge\n" + 
        "profits experienced in the boom, as management ploughed cash and profits into\n" + 
        "bigger and more marginal assets. During those times, production was the main\n" + 
        "game and shareholders were rewarded through soaring stock prices. However,\n" + 
        "this investment proposition relied on prices remaining high. ";

final Image img;
try (InputStream imageResource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Graph.png")) {
    ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(imageResource));
    img = new Image(data);
}

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
PageSize ps = PageSize.A4;;
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, ps);

Rectangle effectivePageSize = doc.getPageEffectiveArea(ps);
img.scaleToFit(effectivePageSize.getWidth(), effectivePageSize.getHeight());
PdfFormXObject pdfFormXObject = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(img.getImageScaledWidth(), img.getImageScaledHeight()));
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfFormXObject, pdfDoc);
try (Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, pdfFormXObject.getBBox().toRectangle())) {
    canvas.add(img);
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(text));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if("graph_add".equals(line)) {
        doc.add(new Image(pdfFormXObject));
    } else {
        doc.add(new Paragraph(line));
    }
}
doc.close();
```

*([AddCanvasToDocument](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/AddCanvasToDocument.java#L52) test `testAddCanvasForRuslan`)*

The result:

[image: screen shot]

---

As an aside: If one adds merely one bitmap to the `Canvas` as in this example, one obviously can add the `Image img` directly to the `Document doc` instead of via the form XObject...